# Can't extract data from Json

Tags: php, json, extract

I can't extract data from json that I got from an api.
I tried for hours, tried all kinds of formats. Read Stackoverflow threads like [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php), but I can't see what I am doing wrong.

This is the code so far:

```
$api_results = '{"status":"0000","data":{"opening_price":"6998000","closing_price":"7270000","min_price":"6750000","max_price":"7997000","average_price":"7188302.5804","units_traded":"78484.9241002","volume_1day":"78484.9241002","volume_7day":"335611.84181738","buy_price":"7268000","sell_price":"7274000","date":"1510563513031"}}';

$results = json_decode($api_results, true);

// Some variations I tried:
var_dump($results->status[1]);
var_dump($results->data[1]->opening_price);
var_dump($results["data"][1]["opening_price"]);
```

End result: NULL NULL NULL

What am I doing wrong?

**Thanks for the answers! I will upvote the working ones. Seems I got confused in the formating!**

Comment: what does `var_dump($results);` give?

Comment: `var_dump($results);` and see what it contains. then you know how to access the data

Comment: Check this.... https://eval.in/898633

Comment: You are using `true` as the second argument to `json_decode` which outputs as an array yet are using object notation to access the data within the decoded string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php

$api_results = '{"status":"0000","data":{"opening_price":"6998000","closing_price":"7270000","min_price":"6750000","max_price":"7997000","average_price":"7188302.5804","units_traded":"78484.9241002","volume_1day":"78484.9241002","volume_7day":"335611.84181738","buy_price":"7268000","sell_price":"7274000","date":"1510563513031"}}';


$results = json_decode($api_results, true);
print_r($results['status']);
echo "</br>";
print_r($results['data']['opening_price']);
```

Try access your array that way.

The output is :

```
0000
6998000
```

Keep an eye for the nested arrays. You need to access their parent array first in order to get their values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I use this solution.

Comment: I forgot the true in encode! haha! oops! +1 as this helped me out

Answer (score 3):

Have you read the documentation of  [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) (or, at least, the accepted answer of the question you linked)? If you pass `TRUE` as the second argument to `json_decode()` (and there is no decent reason to not pass it) then it decodes the JSON to associative [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and not objects.

The elements in a PHP array can be accessed using [the square bracket syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing).

A simple call to [`print_r($results)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) tells its structure:

```
Array
(
    [status] => 0000
    [data] => Array
        (
            [opening_price] => 6998000
            [closing_price] => 7270000
            [min_price] => 6750000
            [max_price] => 7997000
            [average_price] => 7188302.5804
            [units_traded] => 78484.9241002
            [volume_1day] => 78484.9241002
            [volume_7day] => 335611.84181738
            [buy_price] => 7268000
            [sell_price] => 7274000
            [date] => 1510563513031
        )
)
```

Now, accessing its items is a piece of cake:

```
echo($results['status']);
# 0000
echo($results['data']['opening_price']);
# 6998000
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove true from `json_decode` so you will have object result like [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/50109f89effdc9940120ad4ff9185b0b1ab020bc)

```
$results = json_decode($api_results);
var_dump($results->status);
var_dump($results->data->opening_price);
```

When you use `json_decode` with true the returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Remove true from json_decode and try something like this:

```
var_dump($results->status);
var_dump($results->data->opening_price);
```

If you see {} it is refering to objects and [] indicates that it is an array. You're trying to show everything as if they were arrays

Comment: For this to work, the OP must remove the `true` part from `json_decode`. Maybe you should add this to your answer

Comment: True value of second parameter in `json_decode()` sets the output as array so it is not possible to access it with pointer

Answer (score 0):

Use this code like i think work it fine..

```
<?php
$api_results = '{"status":"0000","data":{"opening_price":"6998000","closing_price":"7270000","min_price":"6750000","max_price":"7997000","average_price":"7188302.5804","units_traded":"78484.9241002","volume_1day":"78484.9241002","volume_7day":"335611.84181738","buy_price":"7268000","sell_price":"7274000","date":"1510563513031"}}';
$results = json_decode($api_results);

print_r($results);
var_dump($results->status);
$var = $results->data;
var_dump($var->opening_price);
?>

stdClass Object
(
    [status] => 0000
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [opening_price] => 6998000
            [closing_price] => 7270000
            [min_price] => 6750000
            [max_price] => 7997000
            [average_price] => 7188302.5804
            [units_traded] => 78484.9241002
            [volume_1day] => 78484.9241002
            [volume_7day] => 335611.84181738
            [buy_price] => 7268000
            [sell_price] => 7274000
            [date] => 1510563513031
        )

)

string(4) "0000"
string(7) "6998000"
```

Answer (score -2):

You have set the second parameter of `json_decode()` to `true`. that means the json will be converted to an array so you are not able to access the data using pointer `->` (because it is not an object).

You may access the data like this:

```
var_dump($results['status'][0]);
var_dump($results['data'][0]['opening_price']);
```

P.S: Try `var_dump($results)` to see the exact data, so you know how to access each attribute.

Comment: `$results['status'][1]` is `'0'`, `$results['data'][1]` is not set.